# Git not ignoring files

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I have ran the following in cmd

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

to remove any files that have been committed and shouldn't have. I then added this to my .gitignore file:

```
settings_local.py
*.pyc
```

which should ignore any .pyc files and the local settings file. However, when I try and scan for changed files in git, it finds them!

Comment: Are you using submodules?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything already committed will still be recognized by git even if they would be otherwise ignored by the `.gitignore`. Once you have run `git rm --cached`, you still have to commit the deletion of those files. They should be ignored from then on, unless you forcibly re-add them.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if you were right at first. I clearly got myself muddled up somewhere. Running your command and committing the changes first worked well.

Comment: No problem! It does seem non-intuitive to have to commit the deletion in order to ignore the files in question, but since the files were previously checked in, you have to tell git not to track them anymore.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense now I think about it!